# Finding largest value using tail recursion

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I'm trying to find the largest value of a list using tail recursion. I can't use any auxiliary functions, though...so it must be done using recursion. I've written a function to find the max, starting from the head, but don't know how to implement it starting from the tail!

```
lmax []  = error "empty list"
lmax [x] = x
lmax (x::y::xs) = 
  if x > y then lmax (x::xs)
  else          lmax (y::xs)
```

Comment: With other questions related to "finding the maximum integer in a list" popping up, this smells of a homework assignment. Don't use Stack Overflow for brainless copy-pasting. Ask intelligent questions.

Answer (score 2):

The term "tail recursion" has nothing to do with the tail of a list, it is about the position of a function call.

You could say that a function call is in tail position, or that it is a tail call, if it's the last thing to happen in a function, i.e. no other computations depend on it.

Compare

```
fun foo xs = List.length xs
```

and

```
fun bar xs = 1 + List.length xs
```

In the first, the call to `List.length` is in tail position, because its result is returned immediately.
In the second, since we add 1 to the length, the call *isn't* a tail call.

"Tail recursion" is when a recursive function call is a tail call.

So you're in luck: your function already is tail recursive, since both conditional branches just return the value of a recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun lmax l = let
  fun lmaxh [] a = a
    | lmaxh (x::xs) a = lmax xs Int.max(x,a)
  in
    lmaxh l 0
  end
```

This works, assuming that the values are nonnegative integers.

Comment: I think using int.max is considered an auxiliary function

Comment: In that case, replace it with (if x > a then x else a).

Answer (score 0):

Implementing tail recursion optimizes efficiency, because one doesn't have to evaluate and "pop-off" the stack after creating the recursive calls.

In general, to use tail-recursion, you must store some "memory" from prior computations to compare with in the current one, and update it for future computations, so as to immediately exit the function in the base case.

As such, your function is *already* tail recursive.

However, here is a tail-recursive `maxList` function, more in the spirit of SML :

```
fun maxList l =
   let 
      fun maxListHelper l acc = 
         case l of 
             [] => acc
           | x :: xs' => if x > acc 
                         then (maxListHelper xs' x) 
                         else (maxListHelper xs' acc)
   in
     case l of
         [] => error "Empty List!"
       | x :: xs' => maxListHelper xs' x
   end
```

Your function is written in a *very* Haskell-like syntax with different cases handled on different lines without being *explicitly* declared as nested cases inside a function definition. This is quite alright, but is usually not done in SML.